# Maintain published test results in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Can we migrate published test results while migrating builds from one project to another in Azure DevOps? or is there any way to store those results.

Comment: How's your issue going? Is it solved?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script using Azure DevOps Services REST API:

1. Get all Runs from old Azure DevOps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
2. Get all results for each run from old Azure DevOps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
3. Create previously saved runs in new Azure DevOps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
4. Create previously saved results in new Azure DevOps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: @Preety Mishra does it work for you? Do you need any additional help?

Comment: while creating the previously saved runs in new Azure DevOps I am getting error:-$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -ContentType 'ap …
     |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be
     | null.\r\nParameter name:
     | testRun","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common","typeKey":"VssServiceException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Comment: - powershell: |
       $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.3"$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{
            Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
         }
         $runId = $result.id
    displayName: 'Create test run'
    name: CreateTestRun
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)

Comment: Fetching all the results did work. And I get the results too for each run. Only when I try to create previously runs and results then getting the error that I have posted above.

Comment: Can u add a sample run that you try to save that cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Published tests results will go into **Tests Plan -> Runs** after builds. You can go the `Runs` to check the result.

[image]

Comment: I want to migrate the results to a different project within Azure DevOps.

Comment: If you want to migrate the results, you need to check the rest api that Tomasz provided.